# Guest user unable to see image in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, experience-cloud

I have an LWC which contains an image. The image source is coming from a URL field on the object. The images are being stored as files.

For some reason the image is not rendering for guest users when viewing in incognito.

I have confirmed that the guest user has read access to the object and the field. Let guest users view asset files on public and login pages is enabled. How can I allow the guest user to view these images?

Comment: Is the LWC relying on an apex class? Did you give the guest profile access to the apex class?

Comment: Yes. The guest user has access to the class. I can see that the image url I being returned from the apex method as expected. I’m thinking this might have something to do with access to the ContentAsset where the image is stored.

Comment: Have you confirmed whether whatever you're getting from the server is accurately returned in your LWC (ex. URL is correct)?